# python xml.sax parsing issue with accentuated characters

Tags: python, xml, encoding, sax

The following code causes the well-known "UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode" error:

```
import xml.sax
import io
parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.parse(io.StringIO(u'<a>é</a>'))
```

While

```
import xml.sax
parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.parse(open('foo'))
```

works (the content of file "foo" is `<a>é</a>`).

I need to parse an XML string in my case, not a file.

Is there any solution to my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file contains bytes, and must have some encoding to store Unicode characters, so use a [BytesIO](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object instead:

```
#coding: utf8
import xml.sax 
import io 
parser = xml.sax.make_parser() 
parser.parse(io.BytesIO(u'<a>é</a>'.encode('utf8')))
```

Note: `#coding: utf8` specifies the encoding of the *source file*; `.encode('utf8')` specifies the encoding of the Unicode string to be stored in the `BytesIO` object.  Technically using a non-Unicode string:

```
#coding: utf8
parser.parse(io.BytesIO('<a>é</a>'))
```

will work as well, since byte strings will be in the source file encoding already, but it makes the intent clearer.  The source file and `BytesIO` encoding could be different.